# Grafana & Prometheus: Count for Today

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a constantly increasing counter e.g.

```
my_counter{uid="1", srv="a"}
my_counter{uid="1", srv="b"}
my_counter{uid="2", srv="a"}
my_counter{uid="2", srv="b"}
...
```

and I'd like to build a Grafana dashboard to show what is the diff of the `value` today (since midnight to now).

This is the query that I came up with `sum(increase(my_counter{}[$__range])) by (uid)` and the `$__range` is selected as *"Today so far"* in Grafana.

I would imagine that the "start" value should not matter in this case and the graph should always start from zero since it should be calculating delta's from midnight to now, but that does not seem to be the case.

What would be the best approach to figuring out what is wrong with the query or maybe I am completely misunderstanding how `increase` function works in this case?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT (2020-06-24 16:04 CEST):

I think I am misunderstanding how this works and my question is a bit unclear. To get the count for today I would like to see the `value(my_counter at now) -  value(my_counter at 00:00(CEST))`

Is that even doable in Grafana?

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with your formula. What is wrong with the result you're receiving?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira I think I am misunderstanding how this works and my question is a bit unclear. 

To get the count for today I would like to see `value(my_counter at now) -  value(my_counter at 00:00(cet))`

Is that even doable in Grafana?

Answer (score 1):

`$__range` always delivers - as you have already pointed out - the selected time range. For example 100 minutes. This is what gets passed on to Prometheus in the range selector.

Lets assume a step of 10. The query tells Prometheus to get the rate per second averaged over `$__range` from 0 to 10 times `$__range`. Then averaged over `$__range` from 10 to 20 times `$__range`. So you should get something like this

[image]

I use `$__range` only in combination with the `instant` option in Grafana.

Comment: Step doesn't do any multiplication or otherwise affect the math inside the query. With `query_range` (which is used for graphing) a step of ten means to evaluate the query at 0s, 10s, 20s, 30s etc. from the start - that is how often to take vertical slices to produce samples for the graph. This has no bearing on the value inside the `[]`,  though if step is greater than the range you'll miss data.